# How to find IP address from netbios host name?

Tags: networking, netbios

What network tool can I use under DOS/windows to find the ip address of a netbios host as easily as is done in Linux?

For example under Linux (ubuntu) I can find the ip address like so:

```
# nmblookup imac
querying imac on 192.168.1.255
192.168.1.75 imac<00>
```

Now, this is the IP of the macbook when connected wirelessly

But under windows I can't ping it:

```
C:\>ping imac

Pinging imac.gateway.2wire.net [192.168.1.68] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

And the closest tool I could find returns TWO IPs 
(it returns the hardwired IP even though it got a different IP by connecting wirelessly

```
C:\>nslookup imac
Address:  192.168.1.254
Name:    imac.gateway.2wire.net
Addresses:  192.168.1.68, 192.168.1.75
```

Isnt there a windows command to return only the active IP address for the host?

Answer (score 10):

On Windows, you can try

- **ping -a IP_address** (lookup for both DNS name and NetBIOS name)
- **nslookup IP_address** (this command requires you to have an internal DNS server configured)

I like to use **ping -a** personally.

Comment: `ping -4a` if you are seeing ip6 and need ip4.

Comment: Didn't he ask for the opposit ?

Answer (score 9):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490938.aspx :

```
Nbtstat.exe -a NETBIOSNAME
Nbtstat.exe -A IP
```

Come with Windows XP and upward.

Comment: That doesn't give the IP of the associated name though.

Answer (score 0):

```
nbtstat -a [hostname] -c
```

This gives IP address of NetBIOS name on Windows

Answer (score 0):

on mac OSX, the command is smbutil lookup NETBIOS_NAME

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer as the question is specific to Windows. The information is definitely useful, though